# Search a Column for Specified Text, Then Return the Sum of the adjacent column which contains values to sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am creating a World Cup spreadsheet.

Example:

Team   | Pts |

Brazil | XXX |

Switz. | XXX |

C. Rica| XXX |

Serbia | XXX |

I have another table which displays the Country, Score & whether it was a W (win), L (loss) or T (tie). A WIN will add 3 points, a TIE will add 1 point & a LOSS will add 0 points. Where I put the XXX, I want a formula that will search the table column for the Country Name and ADD up the W's, L's & T's and display the sum of every game there team played with the point system I mentioned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to do some sort of aggregation here, because each team will be playing multiple games.  I'm not an Excel guru, but pivot tables would be one simple way to aggregate scores.  Then, you could use a `VLOOKUP` from the table you showed us against those sum of points.

Comment: Adding three sumifs multiplied by their score will do what you want

Comment: I meant countifs. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS`. I set up a mock table to demonstrate:

The first `COUNTIFS` will count a given teams wins, and then multiple by a factor of 3.
The second `COUNTIFS` will count a given teams ties (no need to multiply here).
Since a Loss equates to 0 points, there is no need to sum or count anything.

Adjust ranges to fit your setup and then auto-fill the equation down your table to calculate for each team.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(D:D, A2, E:E, {"T","W","W","W"}))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula in H2, as below, and drag down as many rows as required

```
=(3*SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$13=$G2),--($C$2:$C$13="W"))+SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$13=$G2),--($C$2:$C$13="T")))
```

Data:

[image: DATA]

You only care about Wins or Ties. So count the wins per country and * 3 and add to that the count of ties, which you don't need to multiply as is 1.

Sumproduct is used to handle the arrays nicely.